# Will object destructuring paired with a spread operator create a new reference in memory?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, destructuring

I have a function where I want to omit a property ('uuid') from an object ('readingListObj') without mutating the object itself.

Will implementing object destructuring paired with the spread operator on the 'readingListItem' object create a new reference for 'uuid' and 'item'?

```
removeId(readingListObj) {
    const { uuid, ...item } = readingListObj // <---will this line create a new ref for'uuid' and 'item'?

    return item
  }
```

Comment: `item` will be a new object if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Also you don't need `{ ...readingListObj }`. Just `const { uuid, ...item } = readingListObj` is enough. You can also directly destructure the parameter itself `removeId({ uuid, ...item }) { return item }`

Comment: just made an edit to make this concise, so the returned 'item' will be a new object in memory?

Comment: Yes. Relevant part of the spec: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-restdestructuringassignmentevaluation . A new object is created in step 3. `uuid` on the other hand will refer to the same value as `readingListObj.uuid`.

Comment: Also you can easily verify this yourself: `var obj = {foo: 42}; var {...obj2} = obj; obj2.foo = 21; console.log(obj, obj2);`.

Comment: `if ('uuid' in readingListObj) delete readingListObj.uuid;` KISS. The point of `{...}` is to easily create new objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to just check

```js
const object1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: {c: 1}};
const {a, ...object2} = object1;

// try to modify basic value property 
object2.b = 3;
console.log(object2.b, object1.b); // returns different values meaning that objects are indeed different

// try to modify object value property
object2.c.c = 2
console.log(object2.c.c, object1.c.c) // returns the same values
```

The second modification returning same values means that even though destructurizing created a new object it didn't do a deep copy of it, so there is still a possibility of mutation of the original object.

Comment: Interesting, So if there is a deeply nested/complex object, after applying the destructuring like i do in my code snippet, then there can still a reference to the original object?

Comment: yes, the destructing will create a new parent object, however it will copy all of it's parameters values, which would be a reference for nested objects

Comment: What about the 'a' const variable? That will still have a reference to the existing object's property as mentioned by @Felix King?

Comment: in this case it is a basic value so it will be new, however if value of a was an object then it would still be the same object, and modifying it's parameters would modify the object1